# JavaScript TypeError: top.frames.plrf is undefined and Error: Permission denied to access property 'PM'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have 2 files:
Ruins.js,
RuinsMap.loc.js

The code is pretty big, so I put a link on both files.
The script that runs both files is:

```
var RuinsPl = function() {
this.help           = "#";
this.name           = "Руины";
this.id             = "Ruins";
this.master         = null;
this.menuitem       = null;
this.created        = false;
this.enabled        = true;
this.enabled        = true;
this.options        = {map: 0, loc: 0, profile: ""};
this.RuinsFrame     = 0;
this.contentHTML    = "";

this.Start          = function(win) {
    var This = this;
    if (win.document.URL.indexOf("/ruines.php") != -1) {
        win.document.getElementById('ione').style.display = "none";
    }
    if ((win.document.URL.indexOf("/ruines.php") != -1 || (win.document.URL.indexOf("/fbattle.php") != -1 && this.options.map > 0)) && !this.RuinsFrame) {
        if (win.document.URL.indexOf("/ruines.php") != -1) {
            var regex = /(\d{6,10})" target="_blank">Лог турнира/;
            var res = win.document.body.innerHTML.match(regex);
            if (res && res.length > 1) {
                this.options.map = res[1];
            }
            this.master.SaveOptions();
        }
        this.RuinsFrame = 1;
        top.document.getElementsByName("main")[0].outerHTML = '<frameset name="ruins" framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="0" cols="*,400">' +
            '   <frame name="main" src="main.php?top=' + Math.random() + '">' +
            '   <frame name="rmap" src="refreshed.html">' +
            '</frameset>';
    } else if (win.document.URL.indexOf("/ruines_start.php") != -1 && this.RuinsFrame) {
        this.RuinsFrame = 0;
        top.document.getElementsByName("ruins")[0].outerHTML = '<frame name="main" src="main.php?top=' + Math.random() + '">';
    }
    if (win.document.URL.indexOf("/ruines_start.php") != -1 && this.options.map > 0) {
        this.options.map = 0;
        this.master.SaveOptions();
    }
    if (this.options.map > 0 && this.RuinsFrame) {
        var html_doc = win.document.getElementsByTagName("head");
        if (html_doc.length > 0)
            html_doc = html_doc[0];
        else
            html_doc = win.document.body;
        var js_plugin = win.document.createElement("script");
        js_plugin.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        js_plugin.setAttribute("src", "http://old-proxy.info/dark/Ruins.js?" + Math.random());
        js_plugin.setAttribute("charset", "utf-8");
        html_doc.appendChild(js_plugin);
        js_plugin = null;
    }
}
this.ApplyOptions   = function() {
    var This = this;
    if (this.master != null) {
        $(this.master.global_options).each(function() {
            if (this.id == This.id) {
                if (this.enabled)
                    This.Enable();
                else
                    This.Disable();
                if (!$.isEmptyObject(this.value))
                    This.options = this.value;
                else
                    This.options = {map:0};
            }
        })
    }
}
this.Enable         = function() {
    this.enabled = true;
    var mi = this.MenuItem();
    if (mi != null) {
        mi.removeClass("input_pl_off");
    }
}
this.Disable        = function() {
    this.enabled = false;
    var mi = this.MenuItem();
    if (mi != null) {
        mi.addClass("input_pl_off");
    }
}
this.MenuItem       = function() {
    if (this.master != null && this.menuitem == null) {
        var This = this;
        This.mid = this.master.menu_id;
        This.cid = this.master.content_id;
        var menu_item = $('<input type="button" value="Руины"/>');
        menu_item.bind('click', function() {
            if (This.master.Current != This) {
                This.master.Current.Dispose();
            }
            This.master.Current = This;
            $(this).css("background-color", "#f0f0f0");
            This.ToggleContent();
        })
        this.menuitem = $(menu_item);
        return this.menuitem;
    } else
        return this.menuitem;
}
this.ToggleContent  = function() {
    var This = this;
    if (!this.created) {
        $(this.cid).html(this.contentHTML);
        this.created = true;
    } else {
        $("#ruins_options").toggle();
    }
    this.master.ResizeFrame();
}
this.Dispose        = function() {
    this.created = false;
    this.MenuItem().css("background-color","");
}
}
```

http://www.old-proxy.info/dark/RuinsMap.loc.js
and /dark/Ruins.js

(it's a plugin for a game)

I get the next errors:  http://clip2net.com/s/6PL9Wc

> TypeError: top.frames.plrf is undefined
> top.frames.plrf.RefreshMap(loc);

and this one:

> Error: Permission denied to access property 'plugin'
> if(typeof(top.frames['plugin'])=='undefined')

Answer (score 0):

in LoadEvent.js insert `document.domain = "oldbk.com";`